# Twilio testing outbound call with ngrok

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm trying to test my outbound calling via Twilio, using my Twilio "test" credentials. It's an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web app that is hosting the endpoints for Twilio to hit. Since I'm running on localhost, they will be hit via ngrok (public endpoint that routes to your localhost).

I have configured a [toll-free] phone number in twilio where voice requests route to my ngrok url.

When I try to execute my test outbound call in my web app, I navigate to a test controller. It fires off some code that ends up executing this:

```
var call = _client.InitiateOutboundCall(
    new CallOptions
    {
        From = "+1" + _fromPhone, // twilio toll-free phone number with base site/ngrok url configured, ie http://{ngrokcode}.ngrok.io
        To = "+1" + phoneNumber, // phone that I want to "answer" and listen to the message
        Url = url, // ngrok url that points to my localhost endpoint to play message, ie http://{ngrokcode}.ngrok.io/message/{forCustomerId}
        IfMachine = "Continue"
    });
```

In this call, the "_fromPhone" is the phone number that I have purchased/configured in twilio, the toll-free number, which is what routes to my ngrok url.

The "phoneNumber" is the phone that I want to call

The "url" is the endpoint that I want twilio to hit so it can "Say" the message to the recipient.

But, using these test credentials, the phone call never goes out. I accidentally ran this same thing, but using the production credentials, and the phone call DID go out (and started ringing on my cell phone), but when I answered, it was silent for about 15 seconds, then it finally said twilio encountered an error.

Looking at the logs for the accidental production call, it said it couldn't connect to my [ngrok] url.

So, two questions, why isn't the phone call getting executed when using my test credentials? And, if/when the phone call goes out, why isn't it executing/hitting my endpoint that contains my "Say" verbs?

Comment: are your ngrok endpoints working by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Test credentials are not used to make test calls, they are used to ensure that calls to the API are working as expected and will not generate calls themselves. [The docs say](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials):

> When you authenticate with your test credentials, we will not charge your account, update the state of your account, or **connect to real phone numbers**.

As for when you made the call with your real credentials, there's more to look into here.

15 seconds is the timeout that Twilio will wait for when trying to connect to an endpoint. This suggests to me that ngrok was working and proxying the request but that your web application was hanging or taking too long to respond.

Can you hit your ngrok endpoints from a browser (or Postman or curl)? Is your web application logging anything that might help when you do access it? Does the ngrok dashboard (available at http://127.0.0.1:4040 when ngrok is running) give you any more insight.

Let me know and I'll update my answer with more suggestions.